# Aiohttp clean architecture. Transaction and so on

Tags: python, architecture, clean-architecture

As mention in `Clean architecture` we have to have some layers in an application, one of this for working with data (database in my case). This layer should be outer than business logic layer.

1. I tried to do with solution (with aiopg driver):

   ```
   async with db.acquire() as conn:  # getting connection from connection pool
       async with conn.transaction():  # start transaction
           user_repo = UserRepository(conn)  # pass connection to repository
           user_workflow = UserWorkflow(user_repo)
           await user_workflow.execute()  # do some stuff...
   ```

Does it violates `clean architecture` principles?
`UserWorkflow` doesn't know about db connections and transactions.

2. Also I'd like to be independent on use `aiopg` directly.
   So I thought to create some internal interfaces and wrap `aiopg` in it.

   ```
   class DbSession:
       def __init__(self, conn):
           self._conn = conn

   class ContextManagerDB(_EngineAcquireContextManager):
       async def __aenter__(self):
           res = await super().__aenter__()
           return DbSession(res)

   class DbSessionFactory:
       def __init__(self, db):
           self._db = db

       def acquire(self):
           coro = self._db._acquire()
           return ContextManagerDB(coro, self._db)
   ```

in this case `DbSession` is internal style interface which located in `repository` layer. Other repositories know about it.
with this wrappers previous will be like:

```
    db = await create_engine(**db_data)
    session = DbSessionFactory(db)
    async with session.acquire() as conn:
        user_repo = UserRepository(conn)  # pass connection to repository
        user_workflow = UserWorkflow(user_repo)
        await user_workflow.execute()  # do some stuff...
```

Is this good solution?